# OpenLayers 6 : populate Source Vector from multiple geoJson depending on current coordinates

Tags: openlayers, geojson

I have multiple GeoJson (based on OSM data) that are stored locally, one for each region of a country. I'm using OpenLayers and I would like to display relevant features of those GeoJson (for instance 10 features max) based on the current view of a map (+ zoom level).

Is there an easy way to populate my vector Source from those multiple GeoJson (loader function) ? It would be like creating my own BBOX strategy (for instance : displaying 10 features at a time in my current box) but instead of collecting data from a remote server, the data would need to be fetched from my local GeoJson.

I've been trying to make my own loader function which loop on all my Geojson features coordinates and compare them to my current box coordinates to populate the source but it's definitely not efficient. I'm not looking for Cluster solution as this would imply to pre-load all the GeoJson first.

Answer (score 0):

Do not reinvent the wheel and use vector tiles - this is precisely what they are for.
`geojson-vt` - https://github.com/mapbox/geojson-vt - can transform a GeoJSON to vector tiles on the fly.

If you don't want to run code on the server, you can use the `VectorTile` class and implement your own `tileLoadFunction`.

Or you can simply hook yourself to the map view and manually load the features - but frankly I do not recommend it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm currently not working on the tiles (as those are directly uploaded from Stamen) but I'm looking for a way to display POI (point of interest) stored in multiple GeoJSON (like restaurant, museum, metro station). As I would need to populate a Vector Source (if I'm not wrong) on the go, depending on my coordinates. Let's say if I'm Auckland I would like to see POI from Auckland, without loading POI from other places...and then when I would pan on the map, i would need to upload POI from my current location : in other words same behaviour as in OSM or GoogleMaps.

Comment: What should happen when you are panning? There will be a moment where multiple POI sets are displayed?
Vector tiles are perfect for what you are doing, if you can run code on your server, `geojson-vt` has the solution for you - it will allow you to load only the features that are present in the area currently displayed

Comment: Yes I would need to see new POI when panning, but those POI needs to act as 'object' as I want the user to be able to interact with them (you click on a POI and it tells you its name, location, ...) - if I create tile, those are like "images" and there are no interaction possible between the user and the POI